# Populate with condition return null in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get all production results where machine name is 'CircuitPrinter'

ProductionResult schema:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const schemaOptions = {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: false },
};

const productionResultSchema = new Schema({
    machineId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Machine' },
    operatorId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Operator' },
    orderId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order' },
    elementId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Element' },
}, schemaOptions);

export default model('ProductionResult', productionResultSchema);
```

Machine Schema

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const schemaOptions = {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
};

const machineSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    status: { type: String },
    date: { type: Date },
    amount: { type: Number },
}, schemaOptions);

export default model('Machine', machineSchema);
```

Service function:

```
async getBar() {
        return ProductionResult.find()
            .populate({
                path: 'machineId',
                match: { name: 'CircuitPrinter' },
            });
    }
```

But in response I get machineId with null
Without `match` I get correct response with full machine data. What's wrong with my condition. Machine with `CircuitPrinter` name exist in database.

```
{
    "_id": "608c532e4051960ef05176f4",
    "machineId": null,
    "elementId": "608c4e914051960ef05176cc",
    "operatorId": "608c4e914051960ef05176d2",
    "orderId": "608c4e914051960ef05176eb",
    "created_at": "2021-04-30T18:57:50.771Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Edited:

Sample data Machines document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608c4e914051960ef05176ed"
    },
    "name": "CircuitPrinter",
    "status": "Running",
    "__v": 0,
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-04-30T18:38:09.326Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-04-30T18:38:09.326Z"
    }
}
```

Sample data ProductionResult document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608c532e4051960ef05176f4"
    },
    "machineId": {
        "$oid": "608c4e914051960ef05176f0"
    },
    "elementId": {
        "$oid": "608c4e914051960ef05176cc"
    },
    "operatorId": {
        "$oid": "608c4e914051960ef05176d2"
    },
    "orderId": {
        "$oid": "608c4e914051960ef05176eb"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-04-30T18:57:50.771Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I add sample data to post above.

Comment: Machine name is not "Foo".

Comment: Eh.. is only example - Foo, Bar. I edited it

Comment: Id of the Machine is not match with machineId of ProductionResult

Comment: It's SAMPLE data... I have 640.000 productions results.